# Radio button value added to an array?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, radio-button

I am building a wizard as a learning project, and I want to have a summary of all the radio buttons checked throughout the wizard on the final page... Do I do this through an array? If so, how do I add each radio button value to an array, then log it to the summary page? Is there another method to do this?　Please help.

Comment: When you refer to page, meaning that there will be a next option to go to a next page? What sort of persistence are you using/ going to use?

Comment: I have 4 divs that have previous/next buttons (image size, image background, image padding, image colour). The user will select an option, for example they may choose to change their image size from three options: 100x100/200x200/500x500, and then on the summary page under Image Size it will have what radio button value they selected eg Image Size: 100x100

Comment: Then yes in that case a javascript array will work just fine, if you had to go to a whole different page then some sort of persistence would have been necessary like having to use session objects or persisting the data to a database.

Comment: If it's okay with you, could you give me an example of how to do it or link me to the right direction? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Okay will post an answer as an example, quickly give me a sec.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be sure to upvote it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, hope it is more or less to what you need:

**HTML**

```
//First HTML DIV
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="image_size" value="100x100"> 100x100<br>
    <input type="radio" name="image_size" value="200x200"> 200x200<br>
    <input type="radio" name="image_size" value="500x500"> 500x500<br>
    <input type="button" value="Next" id="Next_ImageSize" />
</div>
//Second HTML DIV
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="image_color" value="blue"> blue<br>
    <input type="radio" name="image_color" value="green"> green<br>
    <input type="radio" name="image_color" value="yellow"> yellow<br>
    <input type="button" value="Next" id="Next_ImageColor" />
</div>
//Summary HTML DIV
<div>
    <h1>Summary</h1>
    <p id="values"><p>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**: (Using Jquery library)

```
var _SummaryArr = []; //empty array
var _SummaryObj = []; //empty array (used for array of objects)

//Add the selected radio button to the array
$("[name='image_size']").change(function() {
    _SummaryArr[0] = $(this).val(); //Index 0 for the first div
    console.log(_SummaryArr[0]); //log to see the result
});
//Add the selected radio button to the array
$("[name='image_color']").change(function() {
    _SummaryArr[1] = $(this).val(); //Index 1 for the second div
    console.log(_SummaryArr[1]); //log to see the result
});



//Add the selected radio button to the array
$("[name='image_size']").change(function() {
    _SummaryObj[0] = { "image_size" : $(this).val() }; //Index 0 for the first div
    console.log(_SummaryObj[0]); //log to see the result
});

//Adding the values to the summary using array
for (var i = 0; i < _SummaryArr.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) 
        $("#values").html("<span>Image size: " + _SummaryArr[i] + "</span>");

    if (i == 1) 
        $("#values").html("<span>Image color: " + _SummaryArr[i] + "</span>");  
}
//Adding the values to the summary using object array 
for (var i = 0; i < _SummaryObj.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) 
        $("#values").html("<span>Image size: " + _SummaryObj[i].image_size + "</span>");

}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**: (Native)

```
//Get all the radio button elements by name
var rad = document.getElementsByName('image_size');

//Iterate through all the buttons and assign click event listener
for(var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
    rad[i].onclick = function() {
        _SummaryObj[0] = {"image_size":this.value}; //for the first div
        //or
        //_SummaryObj.push({"image_size":this.value});
    };
}

for (var i = 0; i < _SummaryObj.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) //simple check to assign the name (this can easily be replaced by some dynamic function)
        document.getElementById("values").innerHTML = "Image size:" + _SummaryObj[i].image_size;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am not using jQuery, is there a way to do it with just JS?

Comment: Will update now now with native javascript solution.

Comment: There you go buddy.

Comment: Legend. Thank you!

Comment: @tttt if this was the correct answer, can you maybe accept it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways, I would suggest single page web page architecture and to save all the form data(Radio buttons/ or any other data) at your application scope level so that you can access it in the summary page.